# How can I multiply row under certain condition with R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, (aka df), and I want to multiply the Column Price when the column meets a specific condition, such as

> **df$US=='non US'**`.

Here is my code:

```
df$Price <- df$Price[df$US=='non US']*0.85
```

Running the code above causes this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tip*`, CompPrice, value = c(140, 114.117647058824,  : 
  replacement has 142 rows, data has 400
```

I understand the reason the error occurs, however, I don't know how to modify just the rows that meet the condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify the logical condition on the `lhs` of `<-` as the lhs includes the full 'Price' column

```
df$Price[df$US=='non US'] <- df$Price[df$US=='non US']*0.85
```

It is usually recommended to create an object before the assignment to avoid doing the same computation repeatedly

```
i1 <- df$US == 'non US'
df$Price[i1] <- df$Price[i1] * 0.85
```

---

With `data.table`, this syntax is more compact

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[US == 'non US', Price := Price * 0.85]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` like so...

```r
df$Price <- ifelse(df$US=='non US', df$Price * .85, df$Price)
```